# MikroORM failed to connect to database lireddit on postgresql://postgres@127.0.0.1:5432

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql, mikro-orm

I've been trying to solve this bug for 5 hours but it doesn't work. :c   Pls help me.

Here is the ugly console error message(im not pro at formatting sry :c):

```
P:\.Projektek\lireddit-server>yarn dev
yarn run v1.22.10
$ nodemon dist/index.js
[nodemon] 2.0.7
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json  
[nodemon] starting `node dist/index.js`     
[discovery] ORM entity discovery started, using ReflectMetadataProvider
[discovery] - processing entity Post
[discovery] - entity discovery finished, found 1 entities, took 22 ms
[info] MikroORM failed to connect to database lireddit on postgresql://postgres@127.0.0.1:5432
(node:8672) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:8672) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 8)
(node:8672) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

It's so painful.

Comment: Your postgres server is apparently not running or not accessible on localhost (port 5432).

Answer (score 0):

`CREATE USER postgres SUPERUSER;`

try creating postgres db

`createdb {db_name}`

Answer (score 0):

ok, even i have faced this issue. Problem from my end was that database name was spelled incorrectly in my config file.

Here you can do following things.

1. Make sure you have postgres server running
2. Make sure you have created the db of lireddit. Type \conninfo in your postgres terminal it will give details such has database,portnumber and so on.

Hope that helps if not lemme know will guide you. Cheers!